# Rectify my syntax error in mysql triggers

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, triggers, syntax-error

So im trying create a mysql trigger (before update) that would check which attribute of the employee table is getting updated and I will be adding a statement to another table 'Update_Message' which indicates the attribute that gets updated. This is my code :

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER update_col
BEFORE UPDATE
ON Employee FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE Msg VARCHAR(100);
    SET Msg = '';
    IF NEW.eid!=OLD.eid THEN 
       SET Msg = CONCAT(Msg,"trying to update eid");
    ELSE IF STRCMP(NEW.ename,OLD.ename) = 0 THEN
       SET Msg = CONCAT(Msg,"trying to update ename");
    ELSE IF STRCMP(NEW.eaddress,OLD.eaddress) = 0 THEN
       SET Msg = CONCAT(Msg,"trying to update eaddress");
    ELSE
       SET Msg = CONCAT(Msg,"trying to update emonthlysalary");
    DELETE FROM Update_Message;
    INSERT INTO Update_Message (Message) VALUES (Msg);
END;
//
```

It points out a syntax error : ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 17

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html

> ```
> IF search_condition THEN statement_list
>     [ELSEIF search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
>     [ELSE statement_list] 
> END IF
> ```

You're missing the `END IF` that must complete this statement.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but even then, it shows an error for the final INSERT line. Please help me out.

Comment: An error? I wonder what the error is. Or what your code looks like now. But I'm not going to guess.